# an unclear step in a textbook solution of quadratic inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, proof-explanation

We have a quadratic inequality

$$Ax^2+Bx+C>0$$

After solving it for cases where $B^2-4AC > 0$, my textbook turns to cases where $B^2-4AC < 0$:

> Using the perfect square method, let's write down this inequality as
>   $$A\left[\left(X+\frac{B}{2A}\right)^2-\frac{B^2-4AC}{4A^2}\right]>0$$

But how did they get to that result? When I use the formula for completing the square ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square#Formula)), I get

$$A\left(X+\frac{B}{2A}\right)^2-\frac{B^2}{4A}+C>0;$$
$$A\left(X+\frac{B}{2A}\right)^2-\frac{B^2+4AC}{4A}>0$$

Clearly if I factor out $A$ I would not get those $A$'s the textbook has in the second term within the square brackets (and one even an $A$ squared!). Could the texbook be wrong?

P.S. It's just occurred to me - could I just multiply the $\frac{B^2+4AC}{4A}$ by another $A$ to get to that result?

---

Here's the excerpt from the texbook:

[image]

Comment: sorry, what exactly are you asking? how you go from $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ to $A\left[\left(X+\frac{B}{2A}\right)^2-\frac{B^2-4AC}{4A^2}\right]$?

Comment: @Chester - yes, it's not very clear to me.

Comment: That's the way one proves the resolution formulae in high school!

Comment: @Bernard - resolution of quadratic equations?

Comment: @CopperKetle: Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\phantom{{}={}}Ax^2 + Bx + C\\
&=A\left(x^2+ \frac{B}{A} x + \frac{C}{A}\right)\\
&= A\left(x^2+ \frac{B}{A} x + \frac{B^2}{4A^2} - \frac{B^2}{4A^2} +\frac{C}{A}\right)\\
&= A\left(\left(x+ \frac{B}{2A}\right)^2  - \frac{B^2}{4A^2} +\frac{C}{A}\right)\\
&= A\left(\left(x+ \frac{B}{2A}\right)^2  + \frac{4AC-B^2}{4A^2}\right)\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
AX^2 + BX + C&=\frac{1}{4A}\left(4A^2X^2+ 4ABX + 4AC\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4A}\left((2AX)^2+ 2B(2AX)+ 4AC\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4A}\left((2AX)^2+ 2B(2AX)+B^2-B^2+4AC\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4A}\left((2AX+B)^2-B^2+4AC\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{A}\left((AX+\frac{B}{2})^2-\frac{B^2-4AC}{4})\right)\\
&= A\left(\left(x+ \frac{B}{2A}\right)^2  + \frac{4AC-B^2}{4A^2}\right)\\
\end{align*}